# Windows Phone 8 Application fails with the 'ExecutionEngineException'

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

In some cases my Windows Phone application fails with the `ExecutionEngineException`.

There are no real steps to reproduce the fail, so I'm not quite sure where to dig in.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.executionengineexception%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) states that this exception is deprecated and no more thrown in the runtime.

Mostly this exception occurs during the navigation between views (At different places in the code). Sometimes I'm getting this exception while trying to get the response. Particular code below:

```
void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{           
    var request = ar.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;

    try
    {
        if (request == null) return;

        var response = request.EndGetResponse(ar); // at this point I'm getting the exception.
        SetLicenseResponse(response.GetResponseStream());
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        Console.LogError("ResponseCallback exception:" + e.InnerException);
    }
}
```

The external libraries used in the application are:

- [Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.media.smoothstreaming%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/71550)

As well the application consumes two external web services.
The service reference generated is wrapped in async-await service consumers with the usage of the `TaskCompletionSource` classes.

As well there are several quite big ListBoxes that are using the `VirtualizingStackPanel`'s as Items Panels.

According to the information I've found in the internet the exception may be caused if garbage collection is invoked from the parallel threads, however I'm not invoking the `GarbageCollector` in the code explicitly.

Please advice where to start.
Thanks in advance.

**Note**: The application fails with the particular exception mostly while debugging on the device. I'm not using the emulator for the debugging purposes. I haven't noticed that exception in logs while running the application in normal mode, however there is a possibility that the exception was not handled properly to appear in logs.

Comment: may look this, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079564/windows-phone-8-1-c-sharp-app-critical-crash-executionengineexception-only-on)