# Windows Phone 8.1 C# app: critical crash (ExecutionEngineException) only on real device in release mode

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, device, release, executionengineexception

Imagine the following struct type:

```
public struct Token : IDictionary<string, Token>
{
    public readonly object Value;
    public Token(string str) { Value = str; }
    public Token(IDictionary<string, Token> dict) { Value = dict; }

    /* IDictionary<string, Token> implementation is here */
}
```

Don't ask me anything about what it does. Implementation doesn't matter, you can throw NotImplementedException in all methods/properties. It is placed in separate portable class library.

Then imagine the usage of this struct:

```
var token = new Token("111");
var kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, Token>("aaa", token);
var val = kvp.Value.Value;
var t = val.GetType(); // XXX
```

This code works perfectly almost everywhere:

- in desktop app / windows service (haven't tried 'metro' apps)
- on WinPhone 8.1 emulator in any mode (release, debug, with or without debugger)
- on real WinPhone 8.1 device (tried on Lumia 625) in debug mode

But when I run this code on real WP 8.1 device (Lumia 625, latest updates) in RELEASE mode, then I get `ExecutionEngineException` exception at line `XXX` with message `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module.` This exception can't be caught and doesn't contain any details - app just crashes.

Is this a bug? Or known limitations of WinPhone? Why it works on emulator? And all this strange "conditions" are important:

- `Token` must be `struct`, not `class`
- It must implement `IDictionary<K,V>`, not any other interface (tried `IList<Token>`, `ICollection`)
- It must be placed in separate portable class library. If I move it in WP 8.1 project - it works fine
- Instance of `Token` must be placed inside `KeyValuePair<K,V>`. If you do just `token.Value.GetType()` - it works fine

I created VS 2013 solution to reproduce this situation. It can be downloaded [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5259D9757472495B!27589&authkey=!ALpX27Q8e1XhC-w&ithint=file%2czip).

Comment: Try opening an issue on [Microsoft blackhole](https://connect.microsoft.com/)

Comment: I can also see this with my Lumia 1320 (Developer Preview Build 8.10.14203.306). Follow the advice of "CodesInChaos"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the [error report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1037497/windows-phone-8-1-c-app-critical-crash-executionengineexception-only-on-real-device-in-release-mode) at Microsoft Connect couple months ago and have been waiting for response but it doesn't look that somebody in Microsoft is interested in fixing this bug.

By the way I created a more simple repro:

```
public struct Token : IDictionary<string, Token>
{
    /* IDictionary<string, Token> implementation is here */
}
public static class Test
{
    //[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
    public static void Method()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, Token> { { "qwe", new Token() } };
        var arr = dict.ToArray(); // XXX        
    }
}
```

Implementation of `IDictionary<string, Token>` doesn't matter, the exception occurs at line `XXX`. And they (`Token` definition and usage) can be located in one assembly.

I also noticed that adding the `MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)` attribute to a method that uses `Token` fixes the problem, so even considering that I'm not a .NET guru I'm 99% sure that it is a bug in compiler (C#, MDIL, NGEN, whatever) for ARM that is somehow related to optimizations.